# Setting up an Audio Unit format and render callback for interleaved PCM audio

Tags: ios, audio, audiounit

I'm currently attempting to play back audio which I receive in a series of UDP packets. These are decoded into PCM frames with the following properties:

- 2 channels
- interleaved
- 2 bytes per sample in a single channel (so 4
  bytes per frame)
- with a sample rate of 48000.

Every UDP packet contains 480 frames, so the buffer's size is 480 * 2(channels) * 2(bytes per channel).

I need to set up an Audio Unit to play back these packets. So, my first question is, how should I set up the AudioStreamBasicDescription struct for the Audio Unit? Looking at the documentation I'm not even sure if interleaved PCM is an acceptable format.

This is what I've got so far:

```
struct AudioStreamBasicDescription {
   Float64 mSampleRate;                 //48000
   UInt32  mFormatID;                   //?????
   UInt32  mFormatFlags;                //?????
   UInt32  mBytesPerPacket;             //Not sure what "packet" means here
   UInt32  mFramesPerPacket;            //Same as above
   UInt32  mBytesPerFrame;              //Same
   UInt32  mChannelsPerFrame;           //2?
   UInt32  mBitsPerChannel;             //16?
   UInt32  mReserved;                   //???
};
typedef struct AudioStreamBasicDescription  AudioStreamBasicDescription;
```

Secondly, after setting it up, I'm not sure how to get the frames from the UDP callback to the actual Audio Unit rendering function.

I currently have a callback function from the socket listener in which I generate the int16 * buffers that contain the audio I want to play. As I understand it, I also have to implement a render callback for the audio unit of the following form:

```
OSStatus RenderFrames(
    void                        *inRefCon,
    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
    const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
    UInt32                      inBusNumber,
    UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
    AudioBufferList             *ioData)
{
    //No idea what I should do here.
    return noErr;
}
```

Putting it all together, I think what my socket reception callback should do is decode the frames, and put them in a buffer structure, so that the RenderFrames callback can fetch the frames from that buffer, and play them back. **Is this correct?** And if it is, once I fetch the next frame in the RenderFrames function, **how do I actually "submit it" for playback**?

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer if you found a solution? I am doing something very similar and I am wondering if I need to setup ABSD for both the rendercallback output and rendercallback input, or just the playback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking this a section at a time

### AudioStreamBasicDescriptor

Apple's documentation for the ASBD is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/musicaudio/reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html).  To clarify:

- A frame of audio is a time-coincident set of audio samples.  In other words, one sample per channel.  For Stereo this is therefore `2`.
- For PCM formats, there is no packetisation.  Supposedly, `mBytesPerPacket = mBytesPerFrame`, `mFramesPerPacket=1` but I'm not sure whether this is actually ever used.
- `mReserved` isn't used and must be `0`
- Refer to [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/musicaudio/reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) for `mFormatID` and `mFormatFlags`.   There is a handy helper function `CalculateLPCMFlags` in CoreAudioTypes.h for computing the latter of these in `CoreAudioTypes.h`.
- Multi-channel audio is generally interleaved (you can set a bit in `mFormatFlags` if you really don't want it to be).
- There's another helper function that can fill out the entire ASBD - `FillOutASBDForLPCM()` for the common cases of linear PCM.
- Lots of combinations of `mFormatID` and `mFormatFlags` are not supported by remoteIO units - I found experimentation to be necessary on iOS.

Here's some working code from one of my projects:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription inputASBL = {0}; 

inputASBL.mSampleRate =          static_cast<Float64>(sampleRate);
inputASBL.mFormatID =            kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
inputASBL.mFormatFlags =         kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger,
inputASBL.mFramesPerPacket =     1;
inputASBL.mChannelsPerFrame =    2;
inputASBL.mBitsPerChannel =      sizeof(short) * 8;
inputASBL.mBytesPerPacket =      sizeof(short) * 2;
inputASBL.mBytesPerFrame =       sizeof(short) * 2;
inputASBL.mReserved =            0;
```

### Render Callbacks

CoreAudio operates what Apple describe as a *pull* model.  That is to say, that the render call-back is called form a real-time thread when CoreAudio needs the buffer filling.   From your question it appears you are expecting the opposite - pushing the data to the audio output.

There are essentially two implementation choices:

1. Perform non-blocking reads from the UDP socket in the render callback (as a general rule, anything you do in here should be fast and non-blocking).
2. Maintain an audio FIFO into which samples are inserted when receive and consumed by the render callback.

The second is probably the better choice, but you are going to need to manage buffer over- and under-runs yourself.

The `ioData` argument points to a scatter-gather control structure.  In the simplest case, it points to one buffer containing all of the frames, but could contain several that between them have sufficient frames to satisfy `inNumberFrames`.   Normally, one pre-allocates a buffer big enough for `inNumberFrames`, copies samples into it and then modifies the `AudioBufferList` object pointed to buy `ioData` to point to it.

In your application you could potentially a scatter-gather approach on your decoded audio packets, allocating buffers as they are decoded.   However, you don't always get the latency you wanted and might not be able to arrange for `inNumberFrames` to be the same as your decoded UDP frames of audio.

Comment: Thanks, such a comprehensive answer was just what I wanted.

Comment: On reflection, I'm less sure about being able to do scatter gather with the `AudioBufferList`.  It's a general purpose data structure used in a number of different APIs - and the documentation doesn't really cover precisely how it should be used in the render callback. Probably safest to use a single interleaved buffer big enough for `inNumberFrames`.