# filling an audio buffer from an array of bytes and playing using a render callback

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I have an array of bytes that I receive in my obj-c code like this:

```
void sendAudio(int length, Byte* byteArrPtr) {
bufferStream *newBuffer = [bufferStream getInstance];
for (int i=0; i<length;, i++)
{
uint16_t intData = OSReadBigInt16(byteArrPtr,2);
//How do I add intData to buffer here?
byteArrPtr++;
}

}
```

The audio is interleaved, 44.1KHz sample rate, and is sent in bundles of 2048 frames.

My goal is to get this audio data playing on the device using a render callback, but it's not clear to me how to fill an audio buffer with this data and have my remoteIO audio unit pull from the buffer. The closest thing I have found on SO is this post [Setting up an Audio Unit format and render callback for interleaved PCM audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463943/setting-up-an-audio-unit-format-and-render-callback-for-interleaved-pcm-audio?rq=1), where the answer suggest to pre-allocate a buffer for the number of frames (2048 in my case), and have the AudioBufferList object in the render callback point to this new buffer.

I have created a buffer class which I am trying to write and read from which looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface bufferStream : NSObject {
AudioQueueBufferRef *buffer;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign)AudioQueueBufferRef *buffer;
+(bufferStream*)getInstance;

@end
```

and in the implementation:

```
#import "bufferStream.h"

@implementation bufferStream
@synthesize buffer;
static bufferStream *instance = nil;
+(bufferStream*)getInstance
{
@synchronized(self)
{
    if(instance==nil)
    {
        instance = [bufferStream new];
    }
}
return instance;
}

@end
```

I'm stuck on how to go about filling this buffer so I can pull from it elsewhere in my code. Should I even be using AudioBufferQueueRef for this?

Answer (score 0):

AudioBufferQueueRef is a pointer to an AudioQueueBuffer which is a struct. It is an opaque type intended for use with AudioQueueServices. (which, depending on what you want to do, is not a bad way to go).

AudioBufferQueueRef is not an objective-c class and therefor cannot be treated as such.

If you go down the audio units path I suggest creating your own user info struct to handle what you need. The Apple documentation gives examples of this.

I also suggest re-thinking your design pattern you're implementing, as objective-c can have an impact on performance. Best keep it at a C or C++ level where possible.

If you are after a high level alternative look at AVFoundation framework. I think a happy medium is AudioQueueServices which is found in the AudioToolbox framework.

Comment: "If you go down the audio units path I suggest creating your own user info struct to handle what you need. The Apple documentation gives examples of this." 

Can you expand on the user info struct or link to the documentation you refer to? Do you mean set up an AudioStreamBasicDescription? I am intending to publish this audio stream as an inter app audio node eventually, which as I understand it requires that I register an audio unit for IAA

Answer (score 0):

iOS Audio Queues use a pull model, not a push model.  Therefore you don't push the data to the audio driver directly.  Instead your app has to temporarily save the data into an intermediate data buffer (circular queue or fifo), and then return to the run-loop.  Then, when the audio callback function is called, that function can then copy (pull) the amount of data it needs from the intermediate buffer, if available, and update parameters (flags, pointers or indexes) to say that it has.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of Core Audio's pull model. Do you know of any code examples of loading arrays of floats into a circular buffer for playback? Thanks!